# Advices for writing the research statement

Tags: application, writing, faculty-application

I am writing my first research statement to apply for a faculty position. what are the most important parts to focus. I am thinking of dividing it into 3 sections. One for current Research, the second for future research and the third one is for previous research works. Is this a good organization?

What are common mistakes to avoid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing your research statement (and cover letter), it is important to recognize that hiring committees will be swamped with applications. My main advice is to keep it short (2 pages should should be enough to explain your research). You can assume that the readers will be scanning the document and not reading every word, so make the important information stand out, such as key techniques or accomplishments. Cover letter should be 1 page max.

In addition, some applicants write their research statement as a short grant application, with clear motivation and specific aims. Depending on your field, that can be a great strategy. Your research statement will also be the outline for your chalk talk.

Comment: But I am in engineering, and I have many problems to cover in my research statement and 2 pages would be very short. It is 6 pages right now